# MySQLを商用で公開するWebアプリのバックエンドに利用する際のGPL適用範囲について

Tags: mysql, gpl

GPLでは派生するプロジェクトについてもGPLを適用し、再配布の許諾を行わなければならないようですが、
商用で契約を結んだユーザのみが利用するWebアプリケーションについて、DB層にMySQLを利用する場合はユーザに対してWebアプリケーション全体のソースコードの開示を行わねばならないのでしょうか?

Comment: ライブラリをリンクしているわけでもないし、再配布しているわけでもないし不要では？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まず、あなたの「Webアプリケーション」がGPLでなければならないか、については、見解が分かれています。FSFの主張ではGPLでなければならないということになりますが、ライブラリをリンクするだけでは二次的著作物には該当しない、従ってGPLである必要はないという見解もあります。

それはそれとして、Webアプリケーションは利用者に対してサービスを提供しているだけで利用者がソフトウェアの複製を所持しているわけではありません。ソフトウェアがGPLだったとしても、提供者と利用者はGPLに基づいたライセンサー/ライセンシーの関係にはありませんのでソースコードを開示する必要もありません。

これはGPLの抜け穴として認識されておりでそれを防ぐためにAffero GPL(AGPL)が作られたぐらいなので一致した見解と考えて良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

そもそもGPLは大雑把に説明すると「バイナリーを入手した人にソースコードも提供する義務を負う」ものです。

質問の件に当てはめるのであればWebアプリケーションの購入者にGPLの適用される範囲のソースコードを提供する義務が生じます。
Webアプリケーション利用者はそもそもバイナリーを入手していませんから無関係です。